# Javascript If statement in a For loop working in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, if-statement

I am in the process of learning to code and building a picture gallery as part of the learning process for a TeamTreehouse.com contest.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kylenoble/8Wf8r/ and the result when running the code: http://jsfiddle.net/kylenoble/8Wf8r/embedded/result/.

The issue I am running into is clicking an `.i` div that is nested in an `.item` div. After hours of banging my head into a wall, I have narrowed it down to the `if` statement below triggering in Chrome and Safari but not triggering in Firefox.

Here is the specific code:

```
    //Loops through the infoUrl's and populates the info button with
    //infoUrl that matches the imageUrl

    for(i = 0, len = (picturesList.length - 1); i <= len; i ++) {
        var infoUrl = picturesList[i].infoUrl;
        var imageUrl = picturesList[i].imageUrl;
        var displayImage = 'url(' +imageUrl+ ')';
        var currentItemUrl = ($(this).css('background-image'));

        //Matches the imageUrl in the displayImage var with the  
        //corresponding infoUrl and opens the matched infoUrl when 
        //the 'info' button is clicked. 

        if (displayImage === currentItemUrl) {
            console.log('true');
            $('.i').click( function(event) {
                window.open(infoUrl);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        break;
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out why the `if` statement won't trigger in Firefox but will in Chrome and Safari. I really appreciate any help you might be able to provide and I apologize if I've been unclear at any point in this question.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you declare your vars: `for(i = 0` should be `for(var i = 0`

Comment: `console.log(escape(displayImage)); console.log(escape(currentItemUrl));` Do they look the same?

Comment: Did you log the values to compare?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I updated the value. epascarello and Jason P, thanks for the tip. gpgekko beat me to it. This seems to be the issue. The value are not the same. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked in the debugger in Firefox, and it's showing a difference between `displayImage` and `currentItemUrl`.

currentItemUrl: `"url("http://media.nara....ges/16/7/16-0651a.gif")"`

displayImage: `"url(http://media.nara.g...ges/14/14/14-1336a.gif)"`

Note the quotes. I'm not sure why, but it seems Firefox returns the css property differently.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I added an if statement that tested for Firefox and added the extra quotes to the displayImage var if the Firefox test is true. I really appreciate your help.